SIGSEGV when compile with `g++ -march=native -g` on Intel with AVX CPUs
I have a problem with g++14.2 and previous versions.
When I compile my program with g++ -march=native -g, the binary creates a SIGSEGV only in Intel CPUs with AVX instruction set. Not in my ARM64 nor in a Core2Duo Intel.
When I compile my program with g++ -g, the binary runs normally in any platform.
When I compile my program with g++ -march=native -O3, the binary runs normally in any platform (optimized out code?).
The place where the SIGSEGV appears, it seems correct. It is just before a call to a member function from another member function.
The assembly instruction where the SIGSEGV appears is:
=> 0x00007ff6074ea2b3 <+67>:    vmovdqa %ymm0,-0x40(%rbp)

but it seems that (rbp-0x40) is not aligned to 32 bytes:
rbp            0x5fec10

I think that this is compiler specific. But I tried to apply alignas(32) to my definitions like:
alignas(32) band_matrix<const unsigned short*, 10, 2> res2{.....}

but either that way, rbp is not aligned to 32 bytes.
I make a minification of my program, which many times works (probably when rbp is correctly aligned to 32 bytes) and many fails (no output)
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<typename It>
struct container_view
{
    typedef typename It::reference reference;
    typedef std::remove_reference_t<reference> value_type;
    typedef const reference const_reference;

    constexpr container_view(It it, size_t s) noexcept : it(it), s(s) {}

    constexpr It begin() const noexcept { return it; }
    constexpr It end() const noexcept { return it + size(); }

    constexpr reference operator[](size_t i) noexcept { return *(it + i); }

    /// Size of container.
    constexpr size_t size() const noexcept { return s; }

private:
    It it;
    size_t s;
};


template<typename T, typename S = const size_t>
struct shifted_vector
{
    typedef std::remove_reference_t<T> vector_type;     ///< The type of vector.
    T vec;                                              ///< DenseVector of sequential non-zero elements.
    S offset;                                           ///< Offset of first non-zero element.
};


struct band_matrix_jump_iterator
{
    typedef short value_type;
    typedef short* pointer;
    typedef short& reference;

private:
    size_t b;   // matrix's bandwidth
    size_t v;   // matrix's column
    size_t e;   // matrix's column's element's index.
    pointer p;  // Pointer to current element.

public:

    constexpr band_matrix_jump_iterator(pointer p, size_t b, size_t v, size_t e) noexcept
        : b{b}, v{v}, e{e}, p{p} {}

    constexpr band_matrix_jump_iterator &operator++() noexcept { ++e; ++p; return *this; }
    constexpr band_matrix_jump_iterator &operator+=(ptrdiff_t i) noexcept { e += i; p += i; return *this; }
    constexpr band_matrix_jump_iterator operator+(ptrdiff_t i) const noexcept
        { band_matrix_jump_iterator t(*this); t += i; return t; }
    constexpr reference operator*() const noexcept { return *p; }
    constexpr bool operator==(const band_matrix_jump_iterator &it) const noexcept { return e == it.e; }
};


struct band_matrix
{
    typedef short value_type;
    typedef value_type* pointer;

    constexpr size_t columns() const noexcept { return 10; }

    size_t b;
    pointer elements;


//---------------------------------------------------------------- TYPEDEFS OF ITERATORS AND VECTORS


    typedef band_matrix_jump_iterator column_iterator;
    typedef shifted_vector<container_view<column_iterator>, const uint8_t> column_vector;



//--------------------------------------------------------------------------- CONSTRUCTORS / ASSIGNS

    constexpr band_matrix(size_t b) : b{b}, elements(new value_type[10]) {}
    constexpr ~band_matrix() noexcept { delete[] elements; }


//------------------------------------------ GET ROWS, COLUMNS, DIAGONAL AND CORRESPONDING ITERATORS


    /// Return a beginning iterator to column \c i vector.
    constexpr column_iterator column_begin(size_t i) noexcept
    { return column_iterator(elements + i, 0, i, 0); }


    /// Return a vector view of column \c i.
    constexpr column_vector column(size_t i) noexcept
    { return {typename column_vector::vector_type{column_begin(i), 1}, (uint8_t) i}; }
};




using namespace std;

int main()
{
    band_matrix m(0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) m.elements[i] = i;

    // checking columns
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.columns(); ++i)
    {
        auto v = m.column(i);
        cout << (int) v.offset << ": { ";
        for (auto i : v.vec) cout << i << " ";
        cout << "}\n";
    }
}

Is this a g++ bug? my code (above) bug?
Any suggestions? (of course the first suggestion is not to use -march=native)
Update
My CPU is Skylake 2016 and I have a laptop with Ryzen 3, and with:

-march=sandybridge -g it works fine
-march=native -g I have SIGSEGV
-march=skylake -g I have SIGSEGV
-march=haswell -g I have SIGSEGV
-mavx2 -mfma -mbmi -mbmi2 -mmovbe -mlzcnt -mpopcnt -mrdrnd -mf16c -g which -I think- emulates -march=haswell -g it works fine.
If I remove -g but I not place an -O3 SIGSEGV appears too as appears with -g, which seems that -O3 just optimize out some code.

Update:
Compiling with clang++ works fine. This probably makes it a g++ bug.
My g++ (problematic) and my clang++ (working ok!) versions are:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/R/winlibs_staging_ucrt64/inst_gcc-14.2.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders, r2' --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --enable-threads=posix --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-serial-configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --disable-default-ssp --disable-rpath --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-stabs --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --disable-gold --disable-nls --disable-stage1-checking --disable-win32-registry --disable-multilib --enable-ld --enable-libquadmath --enable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-libstdcxx --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-graphite --enable-mingw-wildcard --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-libstdcxx-pch --with-mpc=/c/Prog/winlibs_staging_ucrt/custombuilt64 --with-mpfr=/c/Prog/winlibs_staging_ucrt/custombuilt64 --with-gmp=/c/Prog/winlibs_staging_ucrt/custombuilt64 --with-isl=/c/Prog/winlibs_staging_ucrt/custombuilt64 --disable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-install-libiberty --enable-__cxa_atexit --without-included-gettext --with-diagnostics-color=auto --enable-clocale=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-build-sysroot=/R/winlibs_staging_ucrt64/gcc-14.2.0/build_mingw/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0 -I/c/Prog/winlibs_staging_ucrt/custombuilt64/include/libdl-win32   -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -Wno-error=format' CXXFLAGS='-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0 -Wno-int-conversion  -march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2' LDFLAGS='-pthread -Wl,--no-insert-timestamp -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--high-entropy-va -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,--tsaware' LD=/c/Prog/winlibs_staging_ucrt/custombuilt64/share/binutils/bin/ld.exe
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.2.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders, r2)


(built by Brecht Sanders, r2) clang version 19.1.1
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin


Which exact cpu does this code crash on? This'd be easier for others to reproduce if you changed -march=native to a specific cpu model instead. Where does the crash occur?

Can you come up with a test case that is reproducible on godbolt?

This is reminiscent of Bug 54412.  Are you on Windows by any chance?  Also Bug 97473 but that didn't seem to affect x86.

@AlanBirtles updated answer (I have Skylake 2016)

@NateEldredge Unfortunately my code works fine with the same parameters of g++ and the same architecture in GodBolt.

@NateEldredge yes, Windows 10 x64

Output of gcc -v ?

@NateEldredge check the updated question at the end.

Are you definitely loading the libstdc++ library that came with the compiler? That's often the cause of random mingw crashes. We're still lacking a stack trace

@AlanBirtles I also tried to link statically with all of std libraries without a good result.
I merge complete of my code in one file in GodBolt. It seems that: g++ with the same parameters pass all tests without SIGSEGV. Very interesting. clang++ dies from memory and call me to report a bug. It is here: https://godbolt.org/z/bM1f6f8Eh

It's not particularly surprising it doesn't reproduce on godbolt, Linux gcc is very different to mingw and godbolt won't be using the same cpus

godbolt has a mingw gcc; you can't run the code, but you can see a vmovdqa with no alignment. So this looks very much like bug 54412.

I think this is GCC bug 54412, outstanding since 2012.  It's specific to MinGW.
I reproduced this on godbolt using the MinGW GCC 13.1.0 compiler with -std=c++20 -march=x86-64-v4.  You can't execute the code on godbolt, but at line 182 of the asm you can see a vmovdqa [rbp-96], ymm0 with no associated code to align the frame pointer (it's only guaranteed by the ABI to have 16-byte alignment).
The bug report mentions some possible workarounds.  One is -Wa,-muse-unaligned-vector-move which is supposed to tell the assembler to convert all aligned move instructions to unaligned.  Another is to change the container_view constructor to take its it argument by const reference.  Or, of course, -mno-avx2.
